# Access function from another class

Tags: function, flutter, callback, setstate

Hello guys I'm trying to access function from another class becuse this function establish call and navigat to call page so for sure there will be setState function to update the UI but here is the problem whene the UI got updated from another class the app will go out of the widget tree so i have to use callBack function which is i dont know how pleass help

this is the perant class:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/agora_rtc_engine.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_modular/flutter_modular.dart';
import 'package:flutter_social_messenger/src/modules/auth/domain/entities/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_social_messenger/src/modules/auth/export.dart';
import 'package:flutter_social_messenger/src/modules/notifications/domain/entities/call_msg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_social_messenger/src/modules/notifications/domain/entities/notification.dart';
import 'package:flutter_social_messenger/src/modules/notifications/domain/repository/repo.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

import '../../export.dart';
import './call.dart';

class IndexPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String userId;

  IndexPage(String this.userId);


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => IndexState();
}

class IndexState extends State<IndexPage> {
  /// create a channelController to retrieve text value
  final _channelController = TextEditingController();

  /// if channel textField is validated to have error
  bool _validateError = false;

  ClientRole _role = ClientRole.Broadcaster;

  User  currentUser = Modular.get<AuthController>().currentUser;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // dispose input controller
    _channelController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("target : " + widget.userId.toString() ) ;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Make a Call'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          height: 400,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              /*
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _channelController..text = 'call-' + currentUser.id + "-" +  widget.userId ,

                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          errorText:
                          _validateError ? 'Channel name is mandatory' : null,
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
                          ),
                          hintText: 'call-' +  widget.userId + "-" + currentUser.id ,
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(ClientRole.Broadcaster.toString()),
                    leading: Radio(
                      value: ClientRole.Broadcaster,
                      groupValue: _role,
                      onChanged: (ClientRole value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _role = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(ClientRole.Audience.toString()),
                    leading: Radio(
                      value: ClientRole.Audience,
                      groupValue: _role,
                      onChanged: (ClientRole value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _role = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              */
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child:
                Row( children: <Widget>[
              //    Expanded(child: Text('call-' + currentUser.id + "-" + widget.userId ) ),
                  Expanded( child:
                      RawMaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () => onJoin(widget.userId,context,currentUser.id) ,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.call_end,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 35.0,
                        ),
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        elevation: 2.0,
                        fillColor: Colors.green,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      )



//                      RaisedButton(
//                        onPressed: onJoin,
//                        child: Text('Dial'),
//                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
//                        textColor: Colors.white,
//                      ),


                    ) ], ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  DateTime get now => DateTime.now().toUtc();

  Future<void> sendFollowNotification() {
    String sendToId  = widget.userId;
    final followerId = currentUser.id;

    print("trying to send call notification Id : " + "call-$followerId-$sendToId") ;

    final not = CallNotification(
      id: "call-$followerId-$sendToId",
      sendTo: followerId,
      senderId: sendToId,
      senderName: currentUser.name,
      time: now,
    );
    return repository.sendNotificaion(not);
  }

  Future<void> sendCallAlert() async {
    String sendToId  = widget.userId;
    final followerId = currentUser.id;

    print("trying to send call notification Id : " + "call-$followerId-$sendToId") ;

    final not = CallNotification(
      id: "call-$followerId-$sendToId",
      sendTo: followerId,
      senderId: sendToId,
      senderName: currentUser.name,
      time: now,
    );
    await Modular.get<NotificationsHelper>()
        .registerNotification(followerId, true);
    _callDocument("call-$followerId-$sendToId").setData(not.toJson());
  //  return _callCollection.document(currentUser.id).setData(not.toJson()) ;
    // return repository.sendNotificaion(not);
  }


  final repository = Modular.get<NotificationReposity>();
  final appStore = Modular.get<AppStore>();


  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  DocumentReference _callDocument(String callId) =>
      _callCollection.document(callId);
  CollectionReference get _callCollection => _firestore.collection("calls");


  Future<void> onJoin(String userId,BuildContext context,final _followerId) async {

   //   print("qqqq") ;
    String sendToId  = userId;
    final followerId = _followerId;
    // print(userId+"   i'm");
   // print(_followerId+"  his");
    _channelController.text = "call-$followerId-$sendToId" ;
      print("diallllll : " +  _channelController.text ) ;

      //  /*
    // update input validation
    setState(() {
      _channelController.text.isEmpty
          ? _validateError = true
          : _validateError = false;
    });

    sendFollowNotification();
    sendCallAlert();

    if (_channelController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      print('hiiiiissss');
      // await for camera and mic permissions before pushing video page
      await _handleCameraAndMic();
      // push video page with given channel name
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => CallPage(
            channelName: _channelController.text,
            role: _role,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    // */
  }


  Future<void> _handleCameraAndMic() async {
    // if (kIsWeb || !Platform.isAndroid) return true;

    if (!await Permission.camera.isGranted && !await Permission.microphone.isGranted) {
      var rr = ((await Permission.camera.request()).isGranted && (await Permission.microphone.request()).isGranted) ;
      print("rr : " + rr.toString()) ;
    }
  }


//  Future<bool> checkStoragePermission() async {
//    if (kIsWeb || !Platform.isAndroid) return true;
//    if (!await Permission.storage.isGranted) {
//      return (await Permission.storage.request()).isGranted;
//    }
//    return true;
//  }



}
```

and this is the child:

```
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/agora_rtc_engine.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:styled_widget/styled_widget.dart';
import '../../../../../chat/presentation/calling/index.dart';
import '../../../../../chat/presentation/calling/index.dart';
import '../../../../../chat/presentation/calling/index.dart';
import '../../../../../chat/presentation/calling/index.dart';
import '../../../../../chat/presentation/calling/index.dart';
import '../../../../export.dart';
import '../controller.dart';
import '../../widgets/profile_avatar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_social_messenger/src/modules/chat/presentation/calling/index.dart';
import 'package:flutter_social_messenger/src/modules/chat/presentation/calling/call.dart';




class OProfileHeader extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {

  final OtherUserProfileController controller;

   OProfileHeader({Key key, @required this.controller}) : super(key: key);
  User get user => controller.otherUser;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    print("OProfileHeader : " +  controller.isFollowing.toString() ) ;
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          bottom: 200,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: SizedBox(height: 200)
              .decorated(gradient: AppTheme.primaryGradient),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 150,
          left: 1,
          right: 1,
          child: Center(
            child: Material(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              elevation: 5.0,
              color: theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Observer(
                    builder: (_) => Text(
                      user.name ?? "",
                      style: GoogleFonts.basic().copyWith(fontSize: 28),
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                  ).padding(top: 40),
                  Text(user.status ?? "").padding(bottom: 10),
                ],
              ),
            ).width(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 4 / 5),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 300,
          child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 210,
          child: Center(
            child: Material(
              elevation: 5.0,
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              child: Observer(
                builder: (_) => ProfileAvatarWidget(
                  photoUrl: user.photoUrl,
                  // isLoading: state is LoadingProfilePic,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 200,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 60,
          child: Center(
            child: Observer(
              builder: (_) {
                controller.currentUser.following;
                return RaisedButton(
                  color: controller.isFollowing
                      ? Colors.black
                      : theme.primaryColor,
                  onPressed: () => controller.followUser(user.id),
                  child: Text(
                    controller.isFollowing ? "UnFollow" : "Follow",
                    style: GoogleFonts.alike().copyWith(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ).width(70),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 0,
          left: 200,
          bottom: 60,
          child: Center(
            child: Observer(
              builder: (_) {
                controller.currentUser.following;
                return RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  onPressed: ()=> {
                    IndexState().onJoin(user.id,context,controller.currentUser.id),
                    
                    print(controller.currentUser.id+"    "+controller.currentUser.phoneNumber),
                    print(user.id+"    "+user.phoneNumber)
                  },
                  
                  child: Text(
                    "Call",
                    style: GoogleFonts.alike().copyWith(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ).width(70),

                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ).height(500).backgroundColor(theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor);
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(400);
  //----------------------------------------------------

    // */
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand exactly what you want, but if its how to call a method from a parent widget, if would be something like this:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return ChildWidget(onAction: (resultValue){
       //Do something with the value
     });
   }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget{
      final Function onAction;
      ChildWidget({Key key, @required this.onAction}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Inkwell(
           onTap: (){
              onAction(someValue);
           }
           child: AnyOtherWidget
         );
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah but the method onJoin() has setState() and Navigate.push() so I'm not able to use it from StatelessWidget

Comment: You could make it stateful then.